# Moodle LDAP authentication

Tags: moodle

I'm using moodle 2.7 ,i need to use LDAP authentication for allowing users to login using external LDAP server(with their username and password).i have tried with the apache directory studio.But i got "Invalid login" error.But the login details were correct.

Please suggest me with some other LDAP server and how to add user details in that server and do authentication in moodle.

Answer (score 0):

[FusionDirectory](https://www.fusiondirectory.org/) is a reasonable alternative. It's based on [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) and it's pretty well documented.

Assuming that you're in a Linux environment, [you can install it relatively easily/quickly via SSH](https://documentation.fusiondirectory.org/en/documentation/admin_installation/schema_installation). Once the download is complete, follow the [on-screen instructions](https://documentation.fusiondirectory.org/en/documentation/admin_installation/core_installation) which is not that wildly different from setting up any odd CMS/LMS. The default URL is yourdomain.url/fusiondirectory.

When that's all done and dusted, you'll be taken back to the login page where you can sign in for the first time using the credentials you created during the set up process.

You can use your dashboard to add users/groups.

Once you've got a few users in there, it's now time to jump back to Moodle. Hop over to Site Admin -> Plugins -> Authentication -> Manage Authentication and enable "LDAP Server" then open up its settings. Fill in the details of your LDAP server such that it matches the details of the FusionDirectory.

This will set up the connection, but you will finally need to set up a cron job to regularly sync your databases together. Jump to SSH or cPanel->Cron jobs (Whatever option you prefer) and run the following crontab:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null https://yourdomain.url/auth/ldap/cli/sync_users.php
```

It's up to you how frequently you choose to set it.

HTH.